# Why static fields can't be accessed in class where was created on by specifying the class name

Tags: c#, .net, oop, static

```
internal class Configuration
{
    public static double CurrentFrameRate = 23.976;
    public static string ListViewLineSeparatorString = "<br />";
    private void test()
    {
        // Not accessible here
        this.CurrentFrameRate = 30;
    }
}

class main
{
    // this would work just fine
   private void Test()
   {
        Configuration.CurrentFrameRate = 23.976;
   }
}
```

My question is why static can be accessed in other classes using instance but not in one it was created on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`this` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) is used to refer to the current instance of a class, but since those fields are static, they are not associated with any instance. Try try removing the `this`:

```
private void test()
{
    CurrentFrameRate = 30;
}
```

Or by optionally specifying the class name, like this:

```
private void test()
{
    Configuration.CurrentFrameRate = 30;
}
```

Note that in both of these cases, and in the code you showed for the `main` class, you're never actually referencing any instances of the `Configuration` class. You're referencing the static fields of the class itself.

Comment: @IvandroIsmael I assumed that the *actual* code had it in a method, but I felt like it was important to point that out for the benefit of future readers. I've updated my answer to reflect the code in your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields belong to type itself, and are always referenced by specifying the type name like

```
Configuration.CurrentFrameRate
```

However there is a shortcut for code inside the type itself where you are allowed to omit `Configuration.` part, and just use it as `CurrentFrameRate`